Spring MVC multiple input form validation in spring boot application
Here I have attached my project codes. I am trying to create a crude operation using input form. I have add a javascript code to add additional forms. Suppose, when I click Add Dependent button in formpage.jsp, it will add a similar form except for "bearer" field, because, "bearer" name will be same for all dependent. This example is for a family file submission. A family can have 2, 3, 4 or more members. I hope you understand my concept. As far I know, @Valid ApplicationForm applicationForm  can handle single form. So, how can I add validation in controller class for multiple forms using @Valid ApplicationForm applicationForm ? Because the jsp form will be list of family member info.
Here are the codes of jsp, JpaRepository, controller class and model class
formpage.jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form:form modelAttribute="applicationForm" method="post">
            <form:input type="hidden" path="id" />
            <form:input type="text" path="bearer" />
            <form:input type="text" path="name" />
            
            <form:input type="text" path="description" />
            <form:errors path="description" />
            
            
            <br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="addDependent()">Add Dependent</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form:form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addDependent() {
            var dependentsDiv = document.getElementById('dependents');
            var index = dependentsDiv.children.length;

            var newDependent = `
                <div class="dependent">
                    <form:hidden path="dependents[${index}].id" />
                    <form:label path="dependents[${index}].name">Name:</form:label>
                    <form:input path="dependents[${index}].name" />
                    <br/>
                    <form:label path="dependents[${index}].description">Description:</form:label>
                    <form:input path="dependents[${index}].description" />
                    <br/>
                </div>
            `;
            dependentsDiv.innerHTML += newDependent;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Model class ApplicationForm.java
@Entity
public class ApplicationForm {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @Size(min = 5, message = "minimum 5 characters")
    private String description;

    private String bearer;

    public ApplicationForm(int id, String name, String description, String bearer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.bearer = bearer;
    }

    public ApplicationForm() {
    }

    // Getters and setters

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getBearer() {
        return bearer;
    }

    public void setBearer(String bearer) {
        this.bearer = bearer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id= " + id + ", Name= " + name + ", Description= " + description + ", Bearer= " + bearer;
    }
}

Repository interface FormRepository.java
public interface FormRepository extends JpaRepository<ApplicationForm, Integer> {
}

Controller class HomeController.java
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private FormRepository repo;

    @GetMapping("form")
    public String formPage(ModelMap modelMap) {
        ApplicationForm appForm = new ApplicationForm(0, "user", "");
        modelMap.put("applicationForm", appForm);
        return "formpage";
    }

    @PostMapping("form")
    public String saveForm(@Valid ApplicationForm applicationForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "formpage";
        }
        repo.save(applicationForm);
        return "redirect:/homepage";
    }
}

I want to add validation for multiple forms while @Valid ApplicationForm applicationForm  handle single form.

At the time you submit a form you can't have multiple forms submitted. If you have many input fields they should be placed in the form body tag. The form tag is not displaying, so you can extend it even to the whole document.

There is just one form, the form contains a collection of Dependents that you can just validate.
